# Hibernate Criteria join order by last id

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I need a list of currencies with only the last values of currency history, in sql this query works:

```
    select
      this_.name as y2_,
      this_.id as y3_,
      this_.currency as y4_,
      (select currency_value from currency_history where currency_id = this_.id order by id desc limit 1) as y5_,
      (select date_register from currency_history where currency_id = this_.id order by id desc limit 1) as y6_
  from
      currency this_
```

How i can to this in Hibernate Criteria?

Comment: Do an `ORDER BY id DESC` and restrict the number of results before executing the query/criteria.

Comment: I need a list of results to put in a dataTable, I can't limit results.